# React function getting called on every change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an isomorphic React app. The workflow I am currently working through is :

1. User navigates to the `/questions` route which makes the API call server side and loads the data on the page. This calls the `renderData()` function like it should and loads all the questions for the user to see.
2. User clicks add button to add new question and a modal pops up for a user to enter in the form fields and create a new question.

With every change in the modal, the `renderData()` function is getting called (which it shouldn't). When the user clicks the `Create Question` button, the `renderData()` function is also getting called is throwing an error because the state changes.

I can't pinpoint why the `renderData()` function is getting called every single time anything happens in the modal. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Main component :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './QuestionsPage.scss';
import QuestionStore from '../../stores/QuestionStore';
import QuestionActions from '../../actions/QuestionActions';
import Loader from 'react-loader';
import QuestionItem from '../../components/QuestionsPage/QuestionItem';
import FloatButton from '../../components/UI/FloatButton';
import AddQuestionModal from '../../components/QuestionsPage/AddQuestionModal';

const title = 'Questions';


class QuestionsPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = QuestionStore.getState();
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeMOdal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }

  static contextTypes = {
    onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.context.onSetTitle(title);
    QuestionStore.listen(this.onChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    QuestionStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
}

onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
}

openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true});
}

closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false});
}

createQuestion = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const q = this.state.question;
    q.createdAt = date;
    this.setState({ question : q });
    QuestionStore.createQuestion(this.state.question);
}

textChange = (val) => {
    const q = this.state.question;
    q.text = val;
    this.setState({ question : q });
}

answerChange = (val) => {
    const q = this.state.question;
    q.answer = val;
    this.setState({ question : q });
}

tagChange = (val) => {
    const q = this.state.question;
    q.tag = val;
    this.setState({ question : q });
}

companyChange = (val) => {
    const q = this.state.question;
    q.company = val;
    this.setState({ question : q });
}

renderData() {
    return this.state.data.map((data) => {
        return (
            <QuestionItem key={data.id} data={data} />
        )
    })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
            <div>
                <Loader loaded={this.state.loaded} />
                <FloatButton openModal={this.openModal}/>
                <AddQuestionModal
                    open = {this.state.modalIsOpen}
                    close = {this.closeModal}
                    createQuestion = {this.createQuestion}
                    changeText = {this.textChange}
                    changeAnswer = {this.answerChange}
                    changeTag = {this.tagChange}
                    changeCompany = {this.companyChange}
                />
                { this.renderData() }
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

}

export default withStyles(QuestionsPage, s);
```

Modal Component :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import QuestionStore from '../../stores/QuestionStore';
import QuestionActions from '../../actions/QuestionActions';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import TextInput from '../UI/TextInput';
import Button from '../UI/Button';

class AddQuestionModal extends Component {
    createQuestion = () => {
        this.props.createQuestion();
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.props.close();
    }

    changeText = (val) => {
        this.props.changeText(val);
    }

    changeAnswer = (val) => {
        this.props.changeAnswer(val);
    }

    changeTag = (val) => {
        this.props.changeTag(val);
    }

    changeCompany = (val) => {
        this.props.changeCompany(val);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={this.props.open}
                onRequestClose={this.closeModal} >

                <TextInput
                    hintText="Question"
                    change={this.changeText} />
                <TextInput
                    hintText="Answer"
                    change={this.changeAnswer} />
                <TextInput
                    hintText="Tag"
                    change={this.changeTag} />
                <TextInput
                    hintText="Company"
                    change={this.changeCompany} />
                <Button label="Create Question" onSubmit={this.createQuestion} disabled={false}/>
                <Button label="Cancel" onSubmit={this.closeModal} disabled={false}/>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default AddQuestionModal;
```

On click of

Comment: Since your `renderData()` is called in the render, any state change to `QuestionsPage` will cause this to fire. Your listening to your store and then on every store update your `onChange` will always fire. Your button calls its prop `createQuestion` which then calls your store `QuestionStore` which then restarts your render loop.   You need some logic within your onChange to stop a `setState` if it isnt needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because every change causes you to call the `setState` method and change the state of the main component.  React will call the render function for a component every time it detects its state changing.

- The onChange event on your inputs are bound to methods on your main component
- Each method calls setState
- This triggers a call to render
- This triggers a call to renderData

React allows you to change this by overriding a [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) function.  By default, this function always returns true, which will cause the render method to be called.  You can change it so that only certain changes to the state trigger a redirect by comparing the new state with the old state.

Comment: That works thank you. Do you have any idea why in the `createQuestion()` function in the main component, it is calling `QuestionStore.createQuestion(this.state.question)` but in the `createQuestion()` function, the param holds the entire state?